# TRIGGER and IF IS NULL

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I'm trying to generate automatically a summary for each blog entry IF summary doesn't exists.
So, I've coded this trigger:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_summary 
BEFORE INSERT ON Blog 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF @summary IS NULL THEN
    SET @summary=LPAD(@content, 149, '…');
END IF;
END|
```

Trigger is correctly created.
But when I insert a new entry without summary… nothing happend.
And I don't understand why because summary value IS null.
An example of the INSERT I make:

```
INSERT INTO Blog(title,summary,content,author) VALUES('Test', NULL, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit……', 2);
```

I insert «NULL».  Why my TRIGGER isn't working?

If in case, here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Blog` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `summary` text,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `author` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I want is simple: 
When makink an INSERT:
IF summary is NULL, then, take the first 149 char of «content» and use them as summary.
Just that…

But… why… doesn't it works?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the column in the table.  `@summary` is a variable:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_summary 
BEFORE INSERT ON Blog 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF new.summary IS NULL THEN
        SET new.summary = LPAD(new.content, 149, '…');
    END IF;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```